# Update rows PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, sql-update, postgresql-11

everybody!

I have a table t(id, date1, date2):

```
id        date1           date2
 1    '2020-01-02'    '2020-01-02'
 1    '2020-01-12'    '2020-01-02'
 1    '2020-02-02'    '2020-01-02'
 1    '2020-03-02'    '2020-01-02'
 2    '2020-01-12'    '2020-01-02'
 2    '2020-01-15'    '2020-01-02'
 1    '2020-05-02'    '2020-01-02'
 1    '2020-06-02'    '2020-01-02'
```

I need to update it like this:

```
id        date1           date2
 1    '2020-01-02'    '2020-01-11'
 1    '2020-01-12'    '2020-02-01'
 1    '2020-02-02'    '2020-02-01'
 1    '2020-03-02'    '2020-05-01'
 2    '2020-01-12'    '2020-01-14'
 2    '2020-01-15'    '2999-12-31'
 1    '2020-05-02'    '2020-06-01'
 1    '2020-06-02'    '2999-12-31'
```

in rows with equal id:

```
date2 = date1 [from next row] - 1
```

and for the last date1 in group of equal id:

```
date2 = '2999-12-31'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming you can order your columns by `id` and `date1` in order to find which is the next row, you could use the [LEAD](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-lead-function/), partitioned by `id` to get the next item in the list.

I replicate your case with:

```
create table test (id int, date1 date, date2 date);


insert into test values (1,'2020-01-02','2020-01-02');
insert into test values (1,'2020-01-12','2020-01-02');
insert into test values (1,'2020-02-02','2020-01-02');
insert into test values (1,'2020-03-02','2020-01-02');
insert into test values (2,'2020-01-12','2020-01-02');
insert into test values (2,'2020-01-15','2020-01-02');
insert into test values (1,'2020-05-02','2020-01-02');
insert into test values (1,'2020-06-02','2020-01-02');
```

And I could fetch the following `date1` for each row with

```
select 
    id, 
    date1, 
    date2, 
    coalesce(lead(date1, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY id, date1),'2999-12-31')  date2_next 
from test;
```

Result

```
 id |   date1    |   date2    | date2_next
----+------------+------------+------------
  1 | 2020-01-02 | 2020-01-02 | 2020-01-12
  1 | 2020-01-12 | 2020-01-02 | 2020-02-02
  1 | 2020-02-02 | 2020-01-02 | 2020-03-02
  1 | 2020-03-02 | 2020-01-02 | 2020-05-02
  1 | 2020-05-02 | 2020-01-02 | 2020-06-02
  1 | 2020-06-02 | 2020-01-02 | 2999-12-31
  2 | 2020-01-12 | 2020-01-02 | 2020-01-15
  2 | 2020-01-15 | 2020-01-02 | 2999-12-31
(8 rows)
```

If you're looking for the update statement, check the one below

```
update test set date2=date2_next
from
(select id, 
    date1, 
    coalesce(lead(date1, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY id, date1),'2999-12-31') date2_next 
from test) nxt
where test.id = nxt.id and test.date1=nxt.date1;
```

Comment: Yes, it works, but when I use it in with T as (select ..) update, it gives one value for all rows

Comment: I modified my response to add the update.

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not work if id and date1 duplicated, but for some rows they are

Comment: I resolved question with duplicates by create new table from old with part of this query